# git diff: Show branch name instead of commit hash

Tags: git

`git diff` is a great tool for collaboration, but it may be useful sometimes to have the literal values passed into the `git diff A B` used in the output, instead of the hashes of reference A and B.

Consider the following `git diff` output:

```
$ git diff my-first-branch my-second-branch
diff --git a/file b/file
index c77692b..38ea2ea 100644
--- a/file
+++ b/file
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 Added this file
+Added this line
```

It would be useful to have the *option to* display `my-first-branch..my-second-branch` instead of `c77692b..38ea2ea`, for example.

Are there any options or settings to do this?

**To pre-answer following caveats and answers:**

- *"This breaks reproducibility of the diff"*

  - Local changes may not be shared with others anyway, so the name is helpful if the branches are e.g. `master` and `issue-1234`
- *"Reference names are ambiguous"*

  - I'm not asking for `git reflog` output, but the literal command-line arguments
- *"You can do this with a `sed` one-liner"*

  - This changes many default settings, including disabling the pager, coloring, and various other options since `stdout` is no longer a tty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those wanting to this, a script can handle that:

```
  #!/bin/bash
    
    # prefix git diff with ref names
    ref1=$1
    ref2=$2
    
    if [ -z $ref2 ] 
        then 
             ref1=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
             ref2=$1
    fi  
    
    git diff --src-prefix\=${ref1}\-\- --dst-prefix\=${ref2}\-\- $ref1..$ref2
```

Those unfamiliar with shell scripts can put it txt file named whatever you want to call the command (mine is called gitd).  Then make it executable by using the command: chmod +x 
Next put it in a directory in your PATH variable, I use ~/bin
Finally, when you want to run diff with the branch/commit/whatever use `gitd <whatever> [whatever]`.  Note the first `<whatever>` you chose a branch / commit / whatever.  The second inputted `[whatever]` is optional, causing the first argument to diff to be HEAD, and the second argument to be .

Comment: Can confirm that this works as intended!  https://gist.github.com/zachriggle/a9c61c18c2c5c6022c3ce258f3e3934c

Answer (score 1):

Those id's are for the blobs being diffed, whose names are given above (and with text diffs in the output below) them, e.g. `a/file` is `c77692b`.  The "instead of" you're asking for, with mutable refnames instead of actual blob id's, would be a Very Bad Move.

```
showcmd () { echo "$@"; "$@"; }
```

will get you what you want, e.g. `showcmd git diff master issue-1234 > myoutput`  Or

```
gitdiff() { echo git diff "$@"; git diff "$@"; }
```

and then `gitdiff master issue-1234`.

Comment: The result of `echo` will not be visible in a pager ran by `git diff`.

Comment: @phd So run it through a pager. You've got a toolkit, but that's apparently news, so:  use the tools you have to get the effects you want. Don't ask to have screwdrivers do the job of hammers.  `gitdiff master issue-1224 | less`.  You could even put the pager-piping in the function.  Git knows when it's talking to a terminal and tries to do something reasonable-ish, but full-custom needs a toolkit. Which everybody already has.